# Responsive web to ios conversion, issue with opening third party url

Tags: ios, html, responsive

I converted my responsive web app into an ios app in xcode and built it successfully. I run the simulator,  I logged in and everything is working fine until i click my teleconference button which is supposed to launch cloud meeting landing page and it shows a screen that says "this browser does not support this,  please use safari or google Chrome" hoe can this be resolved

Comment: show ur code. What have you written?

Comment: it looks like that webpage requires particular browsers (or at least particular browser features). How have you implemented your app? have you just embedded the website into a webview?